# What's the order of TypeHandler between java.lang.String and VARCHAR?

Tags: mybatis

There are more than one TypeHandler can hanlde the java type "java.lang.String". For example StringTypeHandler, ClobTypeHandler, NStringTypeHandler and etc.

But

> MyBatis does not introspect upon the database metadata to determine the type.

I guess that mybatis try use them one by one. So is there any order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyBatis does not try them one by one.
When `jdbcType` is not specified, `StringTypeHandler` is used.
Other type handlers are chosen based on the specified `jdbcType`.